# EclipseLink JAXB and JPA memory overhead

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have an application with lots of entities (3000) which needs to be returned by a web services and stored in the database. I've started with Hibernate and CXF / Sun JAXB implementation. After some measurements I've noticed that the memory consumption is very high (another requirement is running on low memory devices).
I've switched from Hibernate to EclipseLink (which reduced memory to forth of the original).
My question is whether switching from Sun JAXB implementation to Moxy will reduce the memory further.
Does EclipseLink JAXB (Moxy) implementation reuse the JPA instrumentation classes?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> Does EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation reuse the JPA
>   instrumentation classes?

You can definitely map the same domain model classes that are used with JPA as with JAXB.  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) has some extensions which make mapping JPA entities to XML easier (support for bidirectional relationships, composite keys, etc).

When writing a large number of objects to XML you may want to consider marshalling to a StAX `XMLStreamWriter` so that you can process the objects as they are pulled from the database.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know whether the JAXB Context memory (including generated classes) will be less than the Sun equivalent? (If all classes in the context are entities as well and were weaved at build time for EclipseLink JPA)

Comment: @AvnerLevy - Unfortunately I don't have any comparison data regarding the memory usage of JAXBContexts.